# Troubles with Exporting Dovecot Post Boxes

Tags: backup, dovecot, export

My postfix/dovecot mailserver runs well, but I want to migrate to another server and my problem: I'm not able to export post boxes from my dovecot:

My command (I replaced the email address):

```
dsync -f -u test@test.com backup maildir:/root/migr_in/data/mailaccounts
```

Then I get this error:

> dsync(test@test.com): Error: user
> test@test.com: Initialization failed: Initializing mail storage from
> mail_location setting failed: stat(/root/migr_in/data/mailaccounts)
> failed: Permission denied (euid=8(mail) egid=8(mail) missing +x perm:
> /root, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0700)

The perms of the target folder "/root/migr_in/data/mailaccounts" is 777.

What do I oversee?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I tried it by overriding the setting, but it anyway doesn't work:

```
dsync -o mail_location=/var/mail/testbox/52 -f -u test@test.com backup maildir:/root/migr_out/data/tmp/tmpexport
```

Same error:

> dsync(test@test.com): Error: user test@test.com: Initialization
> failed: Initializing mail storage from mail_location setting failed:
> stat(/root/migr_out/data/tmp/tmpexport) failed: Permission denied
> (euid=8(mail) egid=8(mail) missing +x perm: /root, dir owned by 0:0
> mode=0700)

The perms for /root/migr_out/data/tmp/tmpexport are 777 and it belongs the same user as the postbox itself (user "mail").

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
The problem was really just that I tried to export to a subdir below /root/. And this is where dsync isn't allowed to write :)
I changed that to a folder outside /root and it worked :)